# Woocommerce wp rest api "Missing OAuth parameter oauth_consumer_key" error and "Invalid signature - provided signature does not match."

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, ionic-framework, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

Basically I want to get the product categories from a site and I am using Ionic and the npm woocommerce api. Whenever I do that from Ionic it gives me the error "Missing OAuth parameter oauth_consumer_key" and the consumer key actually isn't in the link. 
It's blank: "oauth_consumer_key=&" and I looked into the return from the ".authorize()" function and the consumer key is actually undefined. Also, if I fill in the consumer key in the link properly it says "Invalid signature".

If I try with Postman I get "Invalid signature - provided signature does not match.".

I've tried to use the "http" method and also the wocommerce api method with same results. I tried with Postman and it gives the signature error. I've verified if the consumer key and consumer secret is ok from the wp rest api settings on the site. The only thing I saw on the site regarding the plugin was that the php version was lower than 7.2. Could that be a problem? I doubt it, but wanted to mention this anyways.

```
constructor() {
        this.WooCommerce = new WooCommerceAPI({
        url: 'http://example.com',
        consumerKey: 'ck_consumerkey',
        consumerSecret: 'cs_secretkey',
        wpAPI: true,
        version: 'wc/v3',
        queryStringAuth: true // Force Basic Authentication as query string true and using under HTTPS
      });
}
GetCategories() {
return new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
        resolve(this.WooCommerce.getAsync('products/categories').then(function(result) {
            return JSON.parse(result.toJSON().body).product_categories;
        }, (err) =>{
            console.log(err);
        })
        );
    }
    );
}
```

I would expect to get the json list with the categories from woocommerce, but I get only the errors.

So what should I do? I read from some other answers that it might be a problem with the server. If that's true, then how would I go in identifying the problem with the server? And if it's not because of the server configuration, then what would the problem be?

Comment: Check client and server has the same timezone

Comment: Changed the server timezone with my local timezone and verified that it's the same time... still doesn't work. Postman still returns invalid signature. Also generated new keys just to make sure that the keys are correct. Same result.